# SQL / PHP display only upcoming events

Tags: php, date

Hope everyone is awesome.  What is the best way to display only future events in  an event list which is generated by PHP and SQL.

```
function select_events($sql) {
include 'connect.php';

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table id='event-list'>\n
            <tr>\n
                <th id='event'>Event</th>\n
                <th id='date-of-event'>Date</th>\n
                <th id='time'>Time</th>\n
                <th id='place'>Place</th>\n
                <th id='admission'>Admission</th>\n
            </tr>";
}
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $date = new DateTime($row['date']);
    $formatted_date = $date->format('d/m/Y');
    $time = new DateTime($row['time']);
    $formatted_time = $time->format('HH:MM');
    echo "<tr>\n
            <td id='event'>".$row['event']."</td>\n
            <td id='date-of-event'>".$formatted_date."</td>\n
            <td id='time'>".$row['time']."</td>\n
            <td id='place'>".$row['place']."</td>\n
            <td id='admission'>".$row['admissions']."</td>\n
       </tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
}


<?php select_events("SElECT * FROM events ORDER BY date, time"); ?>
```

Thanks everyone in advance.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
<?php select_events("SElECT * FROM events WHERE `date` >= CURDATE() ORDER BY `date`, `time`"); ?>
```

use backticks for mysql reserved keywords

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a condition to check for date and also for time.

Check whether date is greater than today and time is greater than current time.

```
<?php select_events("SElECT * FROM events WHERE `date` >= " . date('Y-m-d') . " AND `time` > " . date('H:i:s') . " ORDER BY `date`, time"); ?>
```